# Storing char array in Neo4j

Tags: arrays, neo4j, character

I'm storing char[] data in Neo4J using the RESTful API in java according to this code snippet:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
..
graphdb = new RestGraphDatabase(...);

char[] charArr = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
Node n = graphdb.createNode("stuff");
n.setProperty("mxcharArr", charArr);
```

If I view the graph through the browser, and when querying the node data back via the API, the data is given as a string:

```
mxcharArr   abc
```

Instead of the expected 'mxcharArr [a,b,c]'. Is this an issue with the REST API or how Neo4J server is storing the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in the RestGraphDatabase. The problem is how it serializes char[] into json (you can have a look at the [source here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/ExecutingRestRequest.java#L150)).

You can use List as a workaround:

```
char[] charArr = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
Node n = database.createNode(...);
List<Character> array = Arrays.asList(charArr);
n.setProperty("mxcharArr", array);
```

Comment: Arrays.asList(charArr) in your workaround can't be cast to List<Character> however your suggestion to use List<Character> does work, just need to use List<Character> array = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c')